# Manually remap HSV to JET colormap

Tags: matlab, mapping, colormap

Is it possible to remap an RGB image (RxCx3) which uses an HSV [*colormap*](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#inputarg_name) (not format!) to an RGB image using a JET colormap? In other words, is there a "mapping" between the HSV and JET colormaps in Matlab?

I haven't thought about it too hard, but here is a quick and dirty attempt:

```
function J = remap( I )

    n = 256;
    X = hsv(n);
    Y = jet(n);
    t = linspace(0,1,n)';

    [r,c,~] = size(I);
    I = reshape( I, r*c, 3 );
    u = interp3( X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3), t, I(:,1), I(:,2), I(:,3) );

    J = I;
    for k = 1:3
        J(:,k) = interp1( t, Y(:,k), u );
    end
    J = reshape( J, r, c, 3 );

end
```

Unfortunately this throws an error on the `interp3` line saying that "*The grid vectors must contain unique points.*". I am not sure my code is the correct thing to do (I am basically trying to fit a 1D embedding coordinate to the HSV colormap), but `size(unique(hsv(256),'rows'),1)==256` is true so I am not too sure why this error occurs.

**NOTE**: it might be confusing to some, but this question has *nothing* to do with the HSV format; all colour images here are stored in RGB format. I am asking about a mapping between [colormaps](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#inputarg_name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this  would be to use your source colormap to convert your image to an indexed image (using [`rgb2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html)) and then convert this indexed image back into an RGB image using the destination colormap (using [`ind2rgb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html))

```
indexed = rgb2ind(img, source_colormap);
output = ind2rgb(indexed, destination_colormap);
```